How to select a PCB material for the high speed design?
I am planning to design a high speed board which has a maximum data transfer frequency of 10Gbps. How to select a PCB material for this design?

Look at materials you would use for a microwave design.

This is also going to depend strongly on the specific application. PCIe for example can tolerate relatively poor materials because the link does so much equalization, but not everything can. Look up the documentation and white papers for your specific data link.

What is the expected trace length for the bus(es) in question?

Curious about an explanation regarding the one vote-to-close "shopping" reason. This, to me, is pretty clearly a "what characteristics are most important to shop for" question, not a "what products have these characteristics I need" question -- more simply, a "how to shop" question, not a "shop for me" question. The former is much more likely to be relevant to readers, and be a more timeless question, than the latter.

This task is not only about choosing the right PCB material, which is actually the last step in the process. You must learn how to do RF designs. This involves at least the following steps:

Read a book about RF design, like e.g. Microwave and RF design
Learn how to use a simulator like HFFS or CST and simulate your design
Make modular design steps - e.g. break your circuit into small pieces and assess the performance of these pieces.
Talk to a PCB manufacturer and choose the required PCB material together with the PCB manufacturer


The selection is mostly influenced by what the transceivers were tested with. You don’t want to be reengineering material choices. If a dev board for the transceivers uses some material, it’s an often a good choice to at least start with.
